# How can I make button which runs as administrator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a button shows a form with administrative priviliges. Is this possible using Visual Studio 2013, Visual Basic?

Comment: Well, do you want to use Operating system's UAC or your own privileges ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't understand what you mean but I came across with those buttons that has administration sign I want to make a button like them, to open a form, to add some registry keys. I learned that it's impossible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That wasn't the answer though. I meant about Windows User Account Control system.

Please post a reference here about what you have learned.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?792815-RESOLVED-Make-button-which-runs-as-administrator "It's not possible to have part of your project running as administrator and another part not running as administrator, but it is possible to either run your whole project as administrator, and also possible to start an external application with administrator privileges from within your project."

Comment: Yep. That's right. And thanks for the reference. Please clear this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that it isn't possible to run part of a project as administrator using Visual Basic 2013. Thanks for the helps.